# How do I set an unlimited timer in ladder logic?

Tags: plc, ladder-logic

I am a newbie at [ladder logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_logic).  The program linked below runs a timer, and updates the delta time between each "frame".

https://www.plcfiddle.com/fiddles/e56c6cf0-d858-4327-b291-7cdc1067ffc1

[image]

The preset value for the timer is set to 10, so the timer stops after 10 seconds.  I want this timer to run indefinitely.  My first guess is to set the preset value to 0 (or a negative number), but this prevents the timer from running at all.

How can I make this function run indefinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to run the timer indefinitely, just reset the timer each **scan** (no such thing as a frame where I come from).

See this [updated fiddle](https://www.plcfiddle.com/fiddles/8aeec528-4cc3-461c-98e1-19cce36e688c).